# Where is the leak here?

Tags: iphone, memory, sdk, memory-leaks

```
-(IBAction)gameplayButtonClicked{

    GamePlayViewController *screen3 = [[GamePlayViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    screen3.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentModalViewController:screen3 animated:YES];
    [screen3 release];
}
```

Comment: There is no leak and no need of a plumber

Comment: instruments is saying there is a leak

Comment: unless GamePlayViewController is leaky? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call presentModalViewController:animated: the screen3 VC will be pushed onto the view hierarchy and retained there.  You should call [dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:) when the modal VC is done which will release it from the view hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

There is no leak. Ensure your project settings are set to debug.